# How to resolve Error 1054 in my code igniter query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a code igniter project hosted [here](http://brandberries.com.ng/clothshop/) but I'm having Error Number: 1054
Unknown column 'p.id' in 'on clause' displayed on the most popular section of the website.

Below is the sql query that is giving this error.

```
public function get_popular()
{
    // Using active records
    $this->db->select('P.*, COUNT(O.product_id) as total');
    $this->db->from('orders AS O');
    $this->db->join('products AS P', 'O.product_id = p.id','INNER');
    $this->db->group_by('O.product_id');
    $this->db->order_by('total','desc');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();        
}
```

with this line of code coursing the issue

```
$this->db->join('products AS P', 'O.product_id = p.id','INNER');
```

The project was working correctly on my local machine until I hosted it here for view

Comment: Table aliases are case sensitive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one is quite simple. You declare an alias for the table as P - capital letter:

```
$this->db->join('products AS P', ...)
```

but then refer to it via a lower letter: `p.id`

On Windows the case of the letters - `P` or `p` - doesn't matter, on Linux (which is probably used by your hosting) it does. So to fix this error just type:

```
$this->db->join('products AS p', 'O.product_id = p.id','INNER');
```

In the future you would do well using strictly lowercase names for tables and fields as that will work on any OS.

Comment: Yes  it does work but threw this threw error. Check the website to see the new error http://brandberries.com.ng/clothshop/

Comment: I have asked the new question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40577561/unable-to-load-the-requested-file-category-php you may try look at it. Thanks.