# Unable to load the requested file: category.php

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have the unable to load the requested file error When the [site is visited](http://brandberries.com.ng/clothshop/). The product which is the first page to be displayed shows the above error so as all product related functions like the product details and the product category respectively.

Below is my products class showing the method that gets all the product, product details and categories.

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Products extends CI_Controller {

public function index()
{
    // Get all products
    $data['products'] = $this->Product_model->get_products();

    // Load View
    $data['main_content'] = 'products';
    $this->load->view('layouts/main',$data);
}

public function details($id)
{
    // Get all products details
    $data['product'] = $this->Product_model->get_product_details($id);

    // Load View
    $data['main_content'] = 'details';
    $this->load->view('layouts/main',$data);
}

public function category($id)
{
    // Get all products details
    $data['products'] = $this->Product_model->get_category_details($id);

    // Load View
    $data['main_content'] = 'category';
    $this->load->view('layouts/main',$data);
}   
}
```

And below is the Product View

```
    <?php if($this->session->flashdata('registered')) : ?>
            <div class="alert alert-success panel-body">
                <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('registered');?>
            </div>
    <?php endif;?>
    <?php if($this->session->flashdata('pass_login')) : ?>
            <div class="alert alert-success panel-body">
                <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('pass_login');?>
            </div>
    <?php endif;?>
    <?php if($this->session->flashdata('fail_login')) : ?>
            <div class="alert alert-danger panel-body">
                <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('fail_login');?>
            </div>
    <?php endif;?>
    <?php foreach($products as $product): ?>
        <div class="col-md-4 game">
            <div class="game-price"> <?php echo $product->price;?></div>
                <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>products/details/<?php echo $product->id;?>">
                    <img src=" <?php echo base_url();?>assets/images/products/<?php echo $product->image;?>" />
                </a>
                <div class="game-title">
                     <?php echo $product->title;?>
                </div>
            <div class="game-add">
                <form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url();?>cart/add">
                    QTY:<input class="qty" type="text" name="qty" value="1"/><br>
                    <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="<?php echo $product->id;?>"/>
                    <input type="hidden" name="price" value="<?php echo $product->price;?>"/>
                    <input type="hidden" name="title" value="<?php echo $product->title;?>"/>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Add To Cart</button>
                </form>            
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endforeach ?>
```

Here's my view folder structure

[image]

Comment: add `__construct()` method with `parent::__construct()` into Products controller

Comment: @smokehill: How would I do that? I'm actually new to code igniter.

Comment: @Narf: Please tell me what would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you have your view file with upper case Category.php.

There for on controller

```
public function category($id)
{
    // Get all products details
    $data['products'] = $this->Product_model->get_category_details($id);

    // Load View
    $data['main_content'] = 'Category'; // match filename
    $this->load->view('layouts/main',$data);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. i have found a solution to this. My views started with capital letter so changed them to lowercase. this solved the problem.

Comment: Its only the controllers and models and libraries that need to have only first letter upper case as stated here http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#php-closing-tag

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure that you are loading views correctly.
you can share your views folder structure with us to lookup this problem

Comment: How can I share the folder structure?

Comment: I have edited the question to include the view folder structure.

Comment: okay, you should have your code in main.php file like this 

$this->load->view('layouts/includes/header');
$this->load->view('layouts/includes/sidebar');
$this->load->view($main_content);
$this->load->view('layouts/includes/footer');

Comment: Below is what I have in mt main.php file

<?php $this->load->view('layouts/includes/header'); ?>
 <?php $this->load->view($main_content); ?>
<?php $this->load->view('layouts/includes/footer'); ?>

Comment: try to load all views directly from your controller method

Comment: How do I do that? In doing what you got I had the following error. http://brandberries.com.ng/clothshop/